# Query Azure DocumentDB that has two attributes with the same name

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to query DocumentDB by the following attribute

```
 "Loop": [
    {
      "@LoopId": "0204",
      "@Name": "Order Information Detail",
      "OID": {
        "OID01": null,
        "OID02": "1NN***"
      }
    },
    {
      "@LoopId": "0210",
      "@Name": "Quantity Information",
      "QTY": {
        "#comment": [],
        "QTY01": {
          "#text": "H9"
        },
        "QTY02": "10",
        "QTY03": null,
        "QTY04": "Pallets"
      }]
```

using the Query

SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Loop[0].OID.OID02="1NN***";

however the same document has another attribute Loop in it:

```
 "Loop": [
{
  "@LoopId": "0100",
  "@Name": "Party Identification",
  "N1": {
    "#comment": [],
    "N101": {
      "#text": "CA"
    },
    "N102": "BN*********",
    "N103": {
      "#text": "2"
    },
    "N104": "B***"
  }
},
{
  "@LoopId": "0100",
  "@Name": "Party Identification",
  "N1": {
    "#comment": [],
    "N101": {
      "#text": "SF"
    },
    "N102": "*****"
  }]
```

is there anyway around this because I need to get the information by OID 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this query, as I think each "row" in the Loop array is a different Loop object:

```
SELECT * FROM Loop c WHERE c.OID.OID02 = "1NN***";
```

Comment: very good thinking but unfortunantly it didn't work I even tried SELECT * FROM Loop c WHERE c.LoopId="0204" AND c.OID.OID02 = "1NN***";

Comment: I found another distinct attribure in the document that I can query the document by. however I'll keep the question to find the answer maybe it'll help someone else . Thank you for your input